# Ruby on Rails: nested each loop within while loop generates error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, while-loop, nested, each

I get a syntax error, when I execute the following code within the rails console:
"syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end"

```
range = 2
my_array = Array.new(range)
a = [1]
i = 0
while i < range do
  a.each do |b|
    puts "test"
  end
  i += 1
end
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? The strange thing is, that the code is working on my server within a ruby file.

Thanks a lot!

tuxware

Comment: How are you executing it in the rails console? are you just pasting it in? that won't work because it breaks apart the code and executes line by line instead of as a complete program.

Comment: Yes I did ;) Thanks for the help, the semicolon did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you're executing it in IRB, it's likely that, as Beerlington said, it's linebreak issues.

It'd explain why it was working in your .rb files but not in IRB...

Solutions? In IRB you can use the semicolon to end a line without executing it... or if you have a long line (which that block of code does not), you can use the classic \ as you would if you were using rails on the command line...

Or... Try [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry). It's an IRB replacement that would be an accommodation for your chunk.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459098/ruby-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input-expecting-keyword-end). if we drop (optional) `do` in the line with a while loop, then this works even in IRB.

```
range = 2
my_array = Array.new(range)
a = [1]
i = 0
while i < range
  a.each do |b|
    puts "test"
  end
  i += 1
end
```