# Ruby SyntaxError: unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby

I am using ruby version 2.4.1, not able to find the cause of syntax error

```
a = 5
while(a>0) do
  a.times do |i|
    puts i
  end
  a = a-1 
end
```

following is backtrace

```
2.4.1 :022 > a = 5
 => 5 
2.4.1 :023 > while(a>0) do 
2.4.1 :024 >     a.times do |i|
2.4.1 :025 >         puts i
2.4.1 :026?>     end
SyntaxError: (irb):26: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.4.1 :027 > a = a-1
 => 4 
2.4.1 :028 > end
SyntaxError: (irb):28: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

when I write some stuff like `puts` statement after while loop then it works. why is this syntax error occurs?

Comment: Works for me :shrug:

Comment: copy-paste mistake.

Comment: The code is fine syntactically. The problem seems to come from irb and how it handles code input line by line. As shown below, pry handles it just fine.

Comment: its not a copy-paste mistake @WillNguyen

Comment: I have tried some other stuff like `print a` before `a.times do |i|` then its works well without any syntax error

Comment: It is really an interesting question, It didn't happened to me before, I have noticed that not only for `times` but also for `(0..a).each do end` didn't work too, Only nested `while` worked on irb, To make the above example work i changed the syntax of the block from `do ... end` to `{..}`, I have nothing to add to @SergioTulentsev comments because it seems to be the most correct answer till now, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452685/ruby-on-rails-nested-each-loop-within-while-loop-generates-error) it seems like it is a known issue and you should use `;` to overcome it.

Comment: Note that if you drop the (optional) `do` in the line with `while`, this works even in IRB

Comment: it works, thanks @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: nested each loop within while loop generates error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452685/ruby-on-rails-nested-each-loop-within-while-loop-generates-error)

Answer (score 1):

Issue will get resolved by adding `;` in front of do statement

```
while(a>0) do;
```

Or you can skip optional `do` as

```
a = 5
while(a>0)
  a.times do |i|
    puts i
  end
  a = a-1 
end
```

Comment: its okay but still confused why it will work when we pass some other stuff like puts after do statement.